# *big.int and *types.transaction issues during interaction of solidity smart contract using Go-ethereum package

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, go-ethereum

I want to interact solidity simple smart contract using Golang based Go-ethereum package, which showing me the error of *types.transaction and *big.int (returning these instead of string and uint) while functions are:

```
function Vote() public payable returns (string memory)
```

```
function Result() public view returns (uint)
```

My question is how can I manage them, so that I can get exactly the same value as required.

I think this is because transaction is being performed before this function call, which may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

By your guess, you have to wait for the transaction to be mined before you can see any resulting value of the transaction.

However, in your case the results are *types.Transaction and *big.Int, this indicates that you are using the deploy-time contract instance, or not initializing the deployed contract (need RPC connection).

You can refer [section "Accessing an Ethereum contract" from here](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/dapp/native-bindings), hope you can find the answer